# IP stack and loopback address

Tags: ip, tcp, ip-address, loopback

The IP address 127.0.0.1 is used to test the IP stack on an individual node. What is IP stack here ?Some blogs redirects this question to TCP/IP stack.But I am unable to co relate and understand it.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TCP/IP Illustrated Volume 1](http://www.cs.newpaltz.edu/~pletcha/NET_PY/the-protocols-tcp-ip-illustrated-volume-1.9780201633467.24290.pdf) discusses at a high level how the loopback address works in the context of an Ethernet driver (see Chapter 2 Section 7, and diagram 2.4). The reason why pinging the loopback address is used is because it verifies the correct operation of the TCP/IP "stack" on a system without it needing to be connected to anything else. Here "stack" is used to refer to a software suite, not a conceptual model, such as the TCP/IP model.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to the [Internet Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_layer) of the [Internet Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol), not specifically to TCP/IP.